# Single square bracket in tabular

Tags: tables, brackets

I am trying to type out the following in a `tabular`:

```
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}l c >{$}l<{$} }
winkel & = &  \left  [0, 360 \)\cup \{\bot \} \right \\
\end{tabular}
```

However, the square bracket after `\left` gives me an error message every time, saying that I have to close it. Is there any way I can get around this? I really just want one square bracket...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suggest you get rid of both `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the `\left` nor the `\right` directives are needed. Get rid of them both. I can also see no reason for encasing `\bot` in a pair of curly braces.

Furthermore, you may want to modify the column type of the middle column to get better spacing around the `=` symbol -- a "relational operator" in TeX-speak.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}l @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} >{$}l<{$} }
winkel & = & [0, 360 ) \cup \bot  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```